# Unable to add textfields vertically in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have added some text fields through story board vertically.Below them i want to add more text fields programatically but it is always adding only one text field.
[image]

Below is the code used

```
 int i;
    self.main_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.scroll_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    for (i=0; i<[arr_customEdtTxt count]; i++)
    {
        JVFloatLabeledTextField *tf = [[JVFloatLabeledTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, y, 270, 27)];
        tf.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        tf.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
        CustomEditText *custom=[arr_customEdtTxt objectAtIndex:i];
        tf.placeholder=custom.field_name;
        tf.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;

        previousTextfield=tf;
        //add bottom border
        [self addBorder:tf];
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.main_view addSubview:tf];
        y=y+27;

        [self.main_view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tf attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.main_view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0] ];

        [self.main_view addConstraint:[  NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tf
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:nil
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                    multiplier:1.0
                                      constant:27.0]];
        [self.main_view addConstraint:[  NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tf
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:self.txt_email
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:0]];
        if(i==0)
        {
            [self.main_view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tf attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.txt_exprience attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:15.0f]];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.main_view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tf attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousTextfield attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:15.0f]];
        }
        [arr_tf addObject:tf];
    }

    [self.main_view layoutIfNeeded];
     [self setDatatoFields];
```

I am getting constraint error i want to add more text fields below the current text fields.Please tell how can i add more and more text fileds below

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `previousTextfield` and `tf` refer to the same textfield in this line:

```
[self.main_view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tf attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousTextfield attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:15.0f]];
```

Also I noticed that at the end you add the textField to `arr_tf` but you also have `arr_customEdtTxt` depending on which one is your array of textFields you should change `previousTextfield = tf` with:

```
if(i > 0){
  //Change arr_tf for arr_customEdtTxt if that is your array
  previousTextfield = [arr_tf objectAtIndex:i-1];
}
```